# Managing data across C/C++ and R

Tags: c++, r

I'm new to R/C++ and have written a C++ program which simulates the motion of a particle under various conditions. In order to analyse the resulting data, I've decided to use R.

The problem I'm having is finding a convenient way to write/read data between C++ and R. My current (naive) solution is to have a `writedata.cpp` function which declares a list of strings that specify which directory I want to write the data to, the names of all the text files and then write the data one file at a time (often invoking a specific function for handling each data type).

After this I need to awkwardly repeat all this code along with the "magic strings" in an R script to read and process the data.

The basic object of the simulation is a `vector<vector<particle>>` whose dimensions are usually around 5000 x 1000000. The `particle` itself looks something like the following:

```
struct particle2D {
    point pos;
    velocity vel; 
    //other observable data 
};
```

Ultimately I want my `writedata.cpp` function to be more flexible so that I could create, for example, a `particle3D` and not have to write lots of specific code to handle the extra dimension. The same goes for simply adding to the list of "observable data" indicated in the above struct.

I know that there are methods for writing a whole struct to a file; however given the amount of data I'm collecting, I'm not sure that it would be the way to go.

Question: Is there some way to fetch a C++ object/struct from within R which doesn't involve the above, rather clunky approach?

Comment: rcpp should be what you want.

Comment: There is no R data structure 'point' or 'velocity'.  But if you can express this as vector, matrix, list, ... then it is _trivial_ to pass it back and forth between R and C++ _without requiring files_.  Which is why we call it seamless.  Read for example the recently updated introductory vignette that comes with Rcpp.

Comment: [This](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette? I've no problem defining my custom data types in R. The (trivial) issue I am facing is figuring out how to pass them to my .cpp program. Do we pass data from within an R script to a .cpp file using the `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` function together with the `env` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question ends on

> Given a program P which generates some data D, how to efficiently store and manage D across different platforms/languages).

and you already said your 'program P' is in C++ -- so you probably want to look at Rcpp. Here are some reasons why:

- seamless data interchange for basic types *without copies*
- you can't beat that: writing that much data to file and reading it back in is slower
- Rcpp covers standard vectors and matrices: essentially every basic *R* data type is mapped
- but the reverse is not true: not every C++ data structure can be mapped automatically so you'd have to convert / adapt
- other advantages: *tooling*
- compilation, linking, loading "just works": on the command-line, in RStudio, whereever
- other libraries: Boost, Eigen, Armadillo, ... already there as are lots of others
- lastly: over 1500 packages on CRAN solving most issues you may have in deployment

So give it a shot. You can get help here and on the rcpp-devel list -- subscribe first so that you can post.

Comment: This looks promising. I will check it out, thank you.

Comment: All seems a bit obscure... I cannot find a single simple example involving some data generated by C++ code which then invokes R functions to produce a plot.

I've looked at several of your articles and blogs and also your GoogleTechTalk. Any other resources available?

Comment: Where do you _want_ to start? There are lots of examples of i) being in R, calling a C++ routine, getting data back and doing work -- like plotting -- with it. There is also ii) being in C++, doing work, and then using RInside to embed R (and still use Rcpp to marshall data).  RInside also has lots of examples, including plotting,